# How to read a file upload from the webpage by django?

Tags: django, forms, frontend, backend

This is the first time I develop a website project, and I don't have any experience in frontend and backend before. I've read Django's official tutorial and get some intuition about it, but I have to say frontend is such a horrible thing, I don't have time to learn it carefully because I have to finish the task before the end of this week.

Here comes the problem. I have to read a file upload by any user from the webpage, the HTML code was written by other people in the lab like follow:

```
<label>select a file &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input id="photoCover" class="input-large" type="text" style="height:30px;">
    <button class="btn1 btn-primary" onclick="$('input[id=lefile]').click();"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;浏览&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
</label>
```

I want to know how to process the file selected in the Django views.

Here are my thoughts:

1.The selected file must be in some directory on the local machine, maybe I should directly get the path of that file.

2.Should I create a form to handle this problem?

Is there anybody could give me a hand or some hints about how to solve this problem? any other resource is appreciated.

Comment: The documentation covers in detail how to handle [file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/). Studying that will answer the questions you have posed above.

Comment: Thank you so much.